# Using CGContext to display a sprite sheet iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sprite, cgcontext

So I have a spritesheet in png format, and have already worked out the coordinates for what I want to display. I'm trying to create a method that will return a UIImage when passed the location information on the spritesheet. I'm just not sure how to use the CGContext stuff along with the the coordinates to return an UIImage.

I was looking to CGContextClipToRect because I think that is the way to do it, but I just can't seem to get it to work.

Something like this

`CGSize size = CGSizeMake(xSize, ySize);

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);

//CGContextClipToRect(spriteSheet.size, imageRect);

[spriteSheet drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(xPos, yPos)];

UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

return newImage;`

returns only what is in the size Context. I need to be able to "move" this size window around the spritesheet if that makes sense.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the call you want to use is `CGImageCreateWithImageInRect`

```
newImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:CGImageCreateWithImageInRect( [spriteSheet CGImage] , imageRect )];
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I was looking all over and all I needed was this one line. Works great

Comment: This is how I did it, but I ran into some performance issues, due to the size of the size and number of sprites used. Using CGImageCreateWithImageInRect, and then copying that image improved animation performance, at the cost of a longer load time.

Answer (score 0):

you need to think of your co-ordinates backwards. The CGSize is fixed. Translate your xPos,yPos so that your sprite appears under the window.