# Iphone Dev: Using one big image (sprite) for all uitableview cells

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have a table view with a list of categories and each category (understand table cell) has a different icon.

I would like to use one big image (sprite) and render different part of the image (single icon) for each row.

Any efficient ideas...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at CGImageCreateWithImageInRect
see the accepted answer to [Using CGContext to display a sprite sheet iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2863626/using-cgcontext-to-display-a-sprite-sheet-iphone/2863689#2863689) for instance.