# how to add sprite sheet images to my application in iphone sdk using objective-c?

Tags: objective-c, ios4

I want to get number of images from Server? It is very expensive to send request and response for each and every image. So I want to get sprite sheet and I want to add these images for my application . I have no idea how to add those images to my application.Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use Core Graphics, as explained in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2863626/using-cgcontext-to-display-a-sprite-sheet-iphone).