# UITableView background image for content

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have UITableView with height = 1000px, I need to set scrollable background.
I know how to set background image for tableview but in this case that background image will not be scrollable.

Right now the only idea how to do that is:
1) create scroll view with proper height (about 1000 px), and set background image for that scroll view. then set frame of UITableView as the bounds of scroll view (and disable scrolling for UITableView).

But my idea is rather bad, because I have many cells with many images on them, and in my approach all the cells will stay in memory.

What is the best way how to implement scrollable background inside tableview?

**P.S.**

I have tableview header of unknown height (depends on the response from server)

Answer (score 1):

If it's a repeatable pattern, one way would be to split the image, repeat the middle part and show the top/bottom only when the `contentOffset` reaches the boundaries of `contentSize`. Or set the top/bottom parts only for first/last cell and the center (repeatable part) for every other.

Edit:

As I said, for a repeatable pattern:

[image: Sample background image]

You crop the elements you'd use for header, footer and middle

[image: Sample cropping lines]

[image: Sample cropped 'components']

Of course, for header & footers with information in them you'd probably need bigger header/footer images:

[image: Sample with bigger header & footer]

Get the parts and assign them as backgrounds in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method. You can do the whole thing with a single image without separating the cropped parts in different files, that's [already discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2863747/1041847).

Comment: can you give some code? because I can't imagine if in this case user really see scrollable background (not appearing of the top during proper moments)

Comment: and I have table header of unknown height (depends on response from server)

Comment: but the main problem is how to synchronize the height of header view (it can be different from 50 to 500 px) with the the background image of first cell

Comment: You can always add parts of the 'middle' after the 'header' part to fill the background of the header view.

Comment: Alexander, in this case pixels at the end of top part and and the begging of middle part will not suit

Comment: That's why my response begins with 'if it's a repeatable pattern'.

Answer (score 0):

There is some example code in the official docs on how to make a "synchronized" scroll view. Since a table view is a scroll view, it should work to synchronize with a table view as well. So make your background be a scroll view behind the table view, and synchronize it.

The critical step is this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                     selector:@selector(synchronizedViewContentBoundsDidChange:)
                     name:NSViewBoundsDidChangeNotification
                       object:synchronizedContentView];
```

Then it's simple in your handler to match up the content offset of your background vs. the table view.

Comment: It's interesting solution, and I will mark it as correct, but please give some code (I don't understand how NSViewBoundsDidChangeNotification for UIView can detect offset of tableview)

Comment: Search iOS docs for synchronizing scroll view. They have the sample code.

Comment: I've tried but didn't find how to synchronize it with table view

Comment: Hmm, oops, it's only in the Mac Cocoa docs, not Cocoa touch. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/NSScrollViewGuide/Articles/SynchroScroll.html That notification doesn't seem to exist on iOS. You might be able to use key-value observing on the center or bounds property of the scroll view instead.